Dropbox FileRequest API - Handling Token Issues - Working with Qualtrics WebService Tasks
I am working on a project that a user completes a Survey Form that is on Qualtrics' platform and has a Webservice task that calls the Dropbox API (https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/file_requests/create) as documented at Dropbox API Documentation: file_requests/create to create a File Request from my Dropbox Account so that the user can upload the required documentation.
While using the Dropbox API Explorer (https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#file_requests_create) for file requests, which showed the format of the HTTP request to be:
POST /2/file_requests/create
Host: https://api.dropboxapi.com
User-Agent: api-explorer-client
Authorization: Bearer {#MY_TOKEN_HERE#}
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "title": "12345678 Smith, John (App #: FA24-1234)",
    "destination": "/FA24-1234 Jones_Martha OTE 1000S Student Smith_John"
}

While the process works when I use the Token that is in the Dropbox App Console, the problem that I am encountering is that the Token created by the Dropbox App Console is no longer a long-living token and expires frequently.
Everything that I am reading about OAuth2 results in the end user having to authenticate into Dropbox, but for this project they are not using their own Dropbox account, and it is only storing to My Dropbox account.
Since the users are not logging into their own accounts, but just sending files to my account, how do I get a token that would allow the File Request to be created?

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Beginner-API-to-create-file-requests/td-p/796763 ]
